# C: "read: Bad Address" and "write: Bad Address"

Tags: c, linux, unix, system

I want to Server-Client model with FIFO's and Client get directory path but I get errors "read: Bad address" and "write: Bad address".

**Client**

Server's Error : "read: Bad address"

Client's Error : "write: Bad address"

Comment: Read some good books about C programming and about Linux programming. Using `strlen(pathName)` as the length parameter to `read` is really wrong, and shows you are confused... After having spent a day or two reading good material, write your program again, compile it using `gcc -Wall -g`, improve it till you get no warnings, and use the `gdb` debugger to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you misuse the return values from `read` and `write`. On success they return positive values, and you handle them as errors.

Also when reading the size of string is not known. So `strlen` is inappropriate.

```
 if( (controlRead = read(fdp,pathName,sizeof(pathName)) ) <= 0)
 {
     // error ...
```

Same condition with `write`.

When transferring strings, it is a good idea to transfer string length as well:

Writing:

```
void write_string(int fd, const char *string)
{
    size_t len = strlen(string);
    write(fd, &len, sizeof(len));
    write(fd, string, len);
}
```

Reading:

```
void read_string(int fd, char *buffer, size_t size, size_t *len)
{
    size_t t_len;

    read(fd, &t_len, sizeof(t_len));
    if (t_len > size) t_len = size;
    read(fd, buffer, t_len);
    if (t_len < size) buffer[t_len] = 0; // null-terminate if there is enough space
    if (len) *len = t_len; // return length if wanted
}
```

Comment: No, `strlen(pathName)` should be `sizeof(pathName)`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes, and that one too. Thank you.